# update manager failed, use previous version to recover

Tags: updates, update-manager, versions

I have an old hardware x86 PC running 12.04.5. I had been ignoring the Update Manager and using the CLI for updates till recently when I decided to use Update Manager, BIG MISTAKE!!!! It hung my system and when I was able to reboot I had lost WiFi, all my printer setups, and more. Recovery mode did not help. I tried loading a driver for a Realtek 8192 dongle but the shell failed because the Manager had left the Modules incompatible with installed Essentials and Headers. I have been booting to the “Previous Version” from GRUB 2 (which has internet access). I want to remove the updated version from my system since I have no trust in what the Manager did. I would like to install the newer kernel and keep the presently working version as backup.
Currently:
kernel 3.2.0-126-generic-pae is GRUB 0,  which is the bad version, no internet etc
kernel 3.2-0-98-generic-pae is GRUB 2  which I can boot into to get internet access. 
Windows XP Professional is GRUB 5 which I need for the SCSI access, not an issue here

lsb_release -a          yields the following
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise

gnome-system-monitor:       yields the following
Release 12.04 (precise) 32-bit
Kernel Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae
GNOME 3.4.2
Hardware: (32 bit) Intel Pentium 4 CPU 3 GHz x 2,  1 GB memory

dpkg -l | grep linux-image  yields the following
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-126-generic-pae      3.2.0-126.169       Linux
kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 32 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-23-generic-pae       3.2.0-23.36         Linux
kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic-pae                3.2.0.23.25         Generic Linux kernel image

I am not sure how the x86 versus the 64bit issue is affecting me. I only want a working system that can be updated to a known state. I would like to clean up the 3.2.0-126 so it can boot and not lose wifi. ("sudo apt-get update"  did not do the job)

Any suggestions would be welcome.

(P.S) The old hardware has PCI cards for SCSI scanner access so I want to keep it but I tried 14.04 LTS once and it had graphics issues. Not my only PC so old versions of Ubuntu are fine.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04LTS is past EOL (may-2017) and is thus off-topic.  The only 12.04 still supported (by Canonical) is Ubuntu 12.04ESM which is not supported here; if you're using 12.04.5 ESM use the phone/email support.

Comment: As noted, Ubuntu 12.04 is EOL. I'd recommend backing up user files and reinstalling a fresh copy of Ubuntu on your machine (you'd probably get better support overall for your hardware issues as well).

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED the problem. I gave up and reinstalled 12.04 from CD. (By the way, how does one edit a post? I could find no links for editing anywhere on the site.) After posting "Solved" finally noticed the almost greyed out "edit" link.